# Object Expected JScript Error in IE8

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Mostly dis can be possibly duplicate. But I dont know why I get this error.
My Script code .

```
    $(document).ready(function () {        
            $(function () {
                $('input[name=Quantity]').blur(allownumbers);
            });

           function allownumbers() {
            alert('ad');
            var elements = document.getElementsByName('Quantity');
            alert(elements);
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {  
            if (elements[i].value == '' || elements[i].value < 1) {
                alert('Please enter a valid value');                    
                return false;
            }
            else if (elements[i].value > 100) {
                alert('Please enter a value less than 100');                
                return false;
            }
            }               
            return true;            
            }​
    });
```

My page code  :

```
   <input id="Quantity" type="text" class="TxtBox" name="Quantity" value="@item.Quantity" onblur="return allownumbers()" maxlength="3"/>
```

And the script references which I have was

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript">
```

What's wrong with my code. Any suggestions ..
EDIT :

The function is not  even called when I dont call it in the textbox.

Comment: Erm... why do you load each component twice: first its full version, then the minified one?

Comment: -1. What line raises the error? And use a decent browser to debug JavaScript errors.

Comment: onblur="return allownumbers()" in my view raises the error and changed my load components also. check my edit.

Comment: @kk1076: To improve the question, click "edit" and supply the missing information.

Comment: This what happens when you try and copy something without understanding it...

Comment: Try taking out the `$(function () { ... });` and putting the event binding and function in the same scope. I was seeing an error about allownumbers not being defined when the event is bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have duplicated your script references.  You need only include each script once (preferrably the minified version unless it is a script you are actively debugging and writing).  Secondly your initialization routine needs some help.

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
        $('input[name=Quantity]').blur(allownumbers);
});

function allownumbers() {
        alert('ad');
        var elements = document.getElementsByName('Quantity');
        alert(elements);
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {  
        if (elements[i].value == '' || elements[i].value < 1) {
            alert('Please enter a valid value');                    
            return false;
        }
        else if (elements[i].value > 100) {
            alert('Please enter a value less than 100');                
            return false;
        }
        }               
        return true;            
        }​
```

Now then, the allownumbers does not have to be outside of the original block, but for me it helps keep my scope clean.  Secondly, $(document).ready ensures that your document is ready for use, so $(function () {}) is not necessary for JQuery call.

So eliminate duplicate script references, and you should be good.

Comment: *"Now then, the allownumbers does not have to be outside of the original block, but for me it helps keep my scope clean."* Actually, it does quite the opposite: It (further) pollutes the global scope.

Comment: how to prevent and restore the value in textbox ?? Like dis document.getElementById("Quantity").defaultValue; , how to use in dis code. ??

Comment: @kk1076: That's a completely different question. Recommend asking it separately. (BTW: It's "this," not "dis." And using correct capitalization, punctuation, and spelling makes it easier for people to understand and help you. If you're struggling, perhaps a colleague, spellchecker, Google translate, etc. can help.)

Answer (score 1):

Your `allownumbers` function doesn't exist at global scope (it's nicely contained within your outermost `ready` handler, which is good; the global scope is polluted enough already), but that's where the old-style DOM0 handler hooked up via the `onblur="..."` attribute on your `Quantity` field's markup is looking for it. That's why when the field blurs, you get that error.

Since you're already hooking it up correctly via jQuery later (in your *inner* `ready` handler), just remove the `onblur` attribute entirely from the field markup.

Other notes:

- You're using `ready` twice: First explicitly, then again inside that callback implicitly by passing a function reference into `$`, which is a shorthand form of the same thing. You can remove the inner one, it's not doing anything other than calling the function inside it.
- You're loading both the unminified and minified scripts. Pick one set, not both.